# Ext.Net LoadMode Merge

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

due to lack of documentation about this feature i can't find a way to do this. I am trying to use autoLoad with merge mode. I have a TabPanel in which each tab is supposed to open autoloading another page using merge mode.

i am aware that plain HTML does render, but pages including Ext.net components fail to render. In my child page i have a resource manager registered with RenderScripts set to 'None' Ext.Net examples page shows a merge mode example in that way.

Right now i get a 'Ext.net.Store is not a constructor' in the child page.

Is there any special parameter which needs to be sent in the loadConfig when doing the autoload? or are there any special elements besides resource manager needed on the child page?

Answer (score 3):

Using `<AutoLoad Mode="Merge" />` is very tricky. In general I'd say it should be avoided, with preference given to using 'XRender' functionality or `<AutoLoad Mode="IFrame" />`.

It's tough to say exactly what's going wrong in your code. Posting a simplified sample demonstrating how you have things configured and demonstrating how to reproduce the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Will look at XRender, seems good enough :), even rather than IFrame.

Comment: Here's a link to a simple XRender sample, see 
http://examples.ext.net/#/XRender/Basic/Add_Items/

Comment: Using Mode="IFrame" is excellent for isolating code/functionality. Anny issues in the frame will be contained and you're not adding weight to the Main app container. Memory consumption and recycling is also handled well.

Comment: @Geoffrey it's true but when you want to make popup shows up (not only in this IFrame page but on the top of the DOM. you got a big problem :(